# LAMP stack without MySQL on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, lamp

I am using a dedicated Google Cloud MySQL instance on a LAMP stack, so how do I go about setting up a LAMP stack without the M in a Compute Engine ?

Does installing the LAMP stack from the marketplace take care of domain name routing etc ?

Is it more feasible to use App Engine for PHP instead of a Compute Engine ?

I need it only for the application - MySQL and Redis are elsewhere.

Comment: You can use App Engine or Cloud Run for PHP, it's fine. MySQL can live on Cloud SQL. If you use LAMP stack, nothing is magic! You have a config file that reference the MySQL database IP. Change it in the configuration, that's all. And YES, App Engine or Cloud Run is much more easier than a compute engine: no backup, no patch, to update, no monitoring (...)

Comment: "And YES, App Engine or Cloud Run is much more easier than a compute engine:" - that's good to hear.